# Mongoose: Browser should not open

Tags: chromium-embedded, mongoose-web-server

The application that I'm developing right now uses Chromium Embedded 
Framework to handle multiple display webapp.

The Mongoose executable is ran by the framework at run time. At the same 
time however, Mongoose runs an instance of Google Chrome.

As much as possible, I want to avoid this scenario.
Is there a way to disable Mongoose from opening a browser but continue with 
the webserver execution?

Answer (score 2):

Add `start_browser no` line to the `mongoose.conf` file. Make sure that `mongoose.conf` file lives in the same directory as mongoose.exe.